# Xamarin.Forms RestSharp not honoring CachePolicy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, restsharp

I am using RestSharp in my Xamarin.Forms Project. Problem is RestClient.ExecuteTaskAsync is returning cached response when accessing same end point without stopping app. I have tried some suggestions like adding Random Number/TimeStamp as parameter, have tried setting header and Cache Policy like

```
_client.AddDefaultHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
_client.CachePolicy = new 
HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

But nothing work. Interesting point is, Cache is not creating problem for one Api Call where I am passing Credentials as Json Body. But for all other API Calls, even changing the parameters doesn't effect. It always bring cached response, until I stop app and then open app again.

I am using MVVM and Dependency Injection, So RestClient Object is passed as Dependency to constructor of class where I am using it. Currently testing in Android not tested in iOS. Please advise.